# Dynamically add component with data to azure map Angular 7

Tags: maps, angular7, azure-maps

I am using Azure Maps and am trying to create a reusable library around their maps web sdk. I want to provide a way for a user to pass in their own popup, along with an array strongly typed objects, to add markers to the page. I have the map and the markers working, but am stuck on how to pass data to the popup. Currently I have:

az-map.component.html

```html
<div class="map-wrapper">
  <div id="az-map"></div>
</div>
<ng-template #defaultMarker>
  <div>
    <img alt="" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/spotlight-poi2.png" />
  </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #defaultPopup>
  <div>
    <h2>~name~</h2>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<div style="display:none">
  <div id="marker" #marker>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="markerTemplate ? markerTemplate : defaultMarkerTemplate"></ng-container>
  </div>
  <div id="popup" #popup>
      <ng-content select="[popupTemplate]"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

az-map.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'az-map',
  templateUrl: './azure-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./azure-map.component.scss']
})
export class AzureMapComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() locations: Location[];
  @Input() mapConfig: AzureMapConfig;
  @Input() markerTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('defaultMarker') defaultMarkerTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild("popup") popupElement: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("marker") marker: ElementRef;

  /* These are the map components we can interact with */
  public map: any;
  public popup: atlas.Popup;
  public symbolLayer: atlas.layer.SymbolLayer;

  private dataSource: atlas.source.DataSource;

  constructor(private configService: ConfigurationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const centerPosition: any = this.mapConfig.center.length
      ? this.mapConfig.center
      : ( this.locations && this.locations.length > 0 ? [this.locations[0].longitude, this.locations[0].latitude] : [-95, 38]);

    this.map = new atlas.Map('az-map', {
      center: centerPosition,
      zoom: this.mapConfig.zoom,
      authOptions: {
        authType: atlas.AuthenticationType.subscriptionKey,
        subscriptionKey: this.configService.get().azureMapKey
      }
    });

    this.map.events.add('ready', () => {
      this.dataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
      this.map.sources.add(this.dataSource);
      this.addMarkers();

      this.symbolLayer = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(this.dataSource, null)
      this.map.layers.add(this.symbolLayer);
      if (this.mapConfig.showControls) {
        this.map.controls.add(new atlas.control.ZoomControl(), {
          position: "top-right"
        });
      }

      if(this.mapConfig.showPopups){
        this.popup = new atlas.Popup({
          pixelOffset: [0, -18],
          closeButton: false
        });

        const _this = this;
        this.map.events.add('mouseover', this.symbolLayer, (e) => {

          if (e.shapes && e.shapes.length > 0) {
            var coordinate;
            const popupHtml = _this.popupElement.nativeElement.innerHTML;

            var props = e.shapes[0].getProperties();
            coordinate = e.shapes[0].getCoordinates();
            _this.popup.setOptions({
              //Update the content of the popup.
              content: popupHtml,

              //Update the popup's position with the symbol's coordinate.
              position: coordinate

            });

            //Open the popup.
            _this.popup.open(_this.map);
          }
        });

        this.map.events.add('mouseleave', this.symbolLayer, (e) => {
          this.popup.close()
        });

      }
    });
  }

  private addMarkers(): void {
    const html = this.marker.nativeElement.innerHTML;

    this.locations.forEach(l => {
      const point = new atlas.Shape( new atlas.data.Point([l.longitude, l.latitude]));
      this.dataSource.add(point);
    });
  }

}
```

and an example of it being used here:

```html
<h1>Account Coverage</h1>
<div class="map-wrapper col-12">
    <az-map [mapConfig]="mapConfig" [locations]="locations" class="col-12 h-50">
        <coverage-popup popupTemplate></coverage-popup>
    </az-map>
</div>
```

This works and shows the popup, but I need to find a way to pass data to the CoveragePopupComponent in the mouseover event in the az-maps.component.ts

One method we tried to use, which works well when you only have a single popup type that needs to be handled was to use the ComponentFactoryResolver like this:

```js
 const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(PopupComponent);
    const component = factory.create(this.injector);

    component.instance.machine = shape.getProperties();
    component.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    const popupContent = component.location.nativeElement;

    this.map.setCamera({
      center: shape.getCoordinates(),
      type: 'ease',
    });

    this.popup.setOptions({
      position: shape.getCoordinates(),
      content: popupContent,
      pixelOffset: [0, -20]
    });
    this.popup.open(this.map);
```

but then you always have to use the PopupComponent type and couldn't use the ng-content stuff we have in the map template.

Comment: Hey Mike, I'm working on a Vue library for azure-maps, it is on its early stages, but you might find it useful. Here's the [AzureMapPopup](https://github.com/rickyruiz/vue-azure-maps/blob/master/src/plugin/components/AzureMapPopup.vue) component.

Comment: I don't have any Angular experience, but from what I understand you have the popup and marker component logic inside the az-map component, can't you extract that logic into each component? Then use props to pass data and watchers to react to changes.

Comment: Can you please show the full `az-map.component.ts` ? How are you importing `atlas` class ?